# Каким образом в Си происходит определение массива, заданной функцией?

Tags: c, функции

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000        /* Максимальная длина строки */

int getline(char s[], int lim);
void copy(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    int len, max;
    char line[MAXLINE], save[MAXLINE];

    printf("Hello! This is an output of the program maxline.c\n");
    max = 0;
    
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(line, save);
        }
    }
    
    if (max > 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", save);

    fflush(NULL);
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
        s[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((s2[i] = s1[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Не понимаю каким образом в этом коде функция getline задает значение массиву line, по сути мы сами передаем массив в функцию в main, но не получаем это значение обратно и вот в моей голове не укладывается как это так получается, что полученные от пользователя данные задаются в массиве и кроме того передаются в другую функцию copy.
Надеюсь правильно свой вопрос изложил.

Answer (score 1):

При вызове функции все аргументы передаются копиями.
*За исключением массивов.* **
На самом деле в функцию передаётся указатель на первый элемент массива. А записи

```c
s [ 7 ] = 3 ;
* ( s + 7 ) = 3 ;
```

идентичны. То-есть к указателю прибавляется индекс и место в памяти модифицируется с помощью звёздочки *.
Работа идёт, модифицируя память массива с помощью указателей на них. И возвращать результат уже не обязательно.

---

** *Массив будет передаваться копией, если он объявлен как элемент структуры.*

```c
struct sarr {
  int arr [ 7 ] ;
} ;
```